# "CSRF validation failed" using "Session Token authentication only"

Tags: 7, services, csrf

Having problem in `CSRF` validation when using `Session Token authentication only` using [services_session_token_auth](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_session_token_auth) `7.x-1.x-dev` module.

already set the token but it keeps throwing `CSRF validation failed`.

I am getting token using
`services/session/token` I follow all the steps in README but no luck to make it work.

anyone can help me to point out what I am doing wrong?

Note: this works in default session authentication.